# Excel convert to h.mm format automatically

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Is it possible to let Excel 2010 not automatically convert a text or number cell into h.mm format?
In other words I've 10 thousand cells that contain numbers and parenthesis like these ones:

```
1.2 (905.A)
1.3 (905.A1B)
etc. etc.
```

If I do find (*) and replace to nothing, Excel automatically convert these cells to h.mm format, also if I set these cells as "Text", so it display:

```
1.02
1.03
etc. etc.
```

instead I want:

```
1.2
1.3
etc. etc.
```

is there a way to do it?

Comment: I cannot replicate this. If I replace the (\*) as you suggest I obtain 1.2, 1.3 (as numbers) in the cells. Perhaps highlight the column and select the General format *before* you do the Replace.

Comment: Andrew, I already done this, but I don't understand this behaviour of Excel. Also if I set Text format before the find/replace...

Comment: On a computer with Win7+Excel2010 it is OK... instead if I use a computer with WinXP+Excel2010 it is not OK... I don't know the reason of these two different behaviour!

Comment: I'm on Windows XP. I can't explain the behaviour either. I would try copying the column to a new column and perform the replace on this to see if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the column formats to text before pasting the values in?

If you are entering the values manually rather than pasting then prefixing the entry with a single quote will make Excel treat the field as literal text:

```
'1.2 (905.A)
```

**UPDATE**

After discussion I now understand that the problem occurs after the data in imported when you try to do a find and replace to get rid of the brackets and anything within them. I cannot replicate this issue, Excel seems to format the remaining number appropriately for me, but as you are still having this issue I would suggest an alternative approach to the find and replace:

If the text you quoted was in cell A1 then in B1 you could use:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

This will return everything before the space. You can then either just hide the column you don't need or copy the new values, right click and do paste special then select values to replace the formulas with their values and therefore remove the need for the old column.

Comment: Yes, I changed the column formats before pasting but the result is the same. I'm entering the values not manually, so I can not put a quote before the value

Comment: If you go through the data import wizard i.e. open an excel file, go to the data tab and click import from text then as part of the wizard you get the option to specify data formats for each column. Have you tried changing the column to text here?

Comment: Yes Chris, the problem is this one, but is when I delete the (*) values fromthe cells...

Comment: what are you attempting to find and replace? If it is a literal * character then this is also what is used for wildcards.

Comment: Sorry, I understand now, you are trying to replace the brackets and everything within them. Unfortunately I am also unable to replicate, this works just fine for me. I will post an alternative solution to the updated answer above.